# Relative links issue with Visio 2007

Tags: visio

When using the "Use relative path for hyperlink" feature, it appears to only apply for network paths unless the target file happens to be reside in the same directory.

If your relative path contains any forward slashes, e.g. path/to/file.htm Microsoft converts them all to backslashes and the relative path can't be viewed in the browser...

I would like to be able to do this so I can move the folder anywhere without having to update all the links.

Is there any way around this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was setting the Hyperlink Base to be the base URL shared by all the pages in the website.

Answer (score 0):

```
Why would a relative path contain forward slashes?
```

So something up a directory would be `.\someSubDirectory` 
and something back a directory would be

```
..\MyParentDirectory
```

and you can combine those

```
..\..\MyParentsParent and .\SubDir\SubSubDir.
```

Do you have a specific example I could help with?

Comment: The forward slashes are for relative internet addresses.